# Deshacer inserciones en tablas debido a excepción por rollback En otras Inserciones

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Se Tienen 3 tablas que se alimenta de un formulario; al realizar las inserciones realiza bien las iniciales pero si falla una (de las ultimas) debería realizar un RollBack o borrado de las tablas que realizo bien la inserción, Para las 2 ultimas realice el siguiente codigo:

```
using (ApplicactionDbContext Db = new ApplicactionDbContext())
        {

            using (var DbCntxTransaction = Db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {

                    Db.Add(Areas);
                    Db.SaveChanges();
                    DbCntxTransaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    DbCntxTransaction.Rollback();
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + " el Error");
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```

Deseo tener una variable o al momento de indicar que se hace un rollback llamar a la otra tabla que no fue exitoso la inserción

```
   if(!db rollback o Variable){ //<-- de las otras tablas
    Db.Add(Producto);
    Db.SaveChanges();
    DbCntxTransaction.Commit();
   }else
     DbCntxTransaction.Rollback();
```

Existe algo parecido o que alguien halla hecho esto? si hay documentación de Entity Framework me gustaría que la suministrarán

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias usar la siguiente instruccion:

```
        using (TransactionScope Inserta = new TransactionScope())
                        {
                            try
                            {//instruccion que inserta en la tablas
Inserta.Complete(); //Este es parecido al commit tran}
                                   }
    
    catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Inserta.Dispose(); //deshace la insercion
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR AL INSERTAR",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                            
                            }
```

si ocurre algun error en cualquiera de las inserciones, este instruccion revierte todo lo insertado en todas las tablas.

Comment: no veo la diferencia, Recuerda que si hago scope, el scope se perdería cuando ya he insertado en una tabla???

Comment: en teoria no, por eso todas tus transacciones van dentro de un solo try catch que asu vez estan dentro de un solo scope, si falla alguna de esas transacciones tendria que revertir todo en las 3 tablas, a menos que vayas usar 3 scope para cada transaccion, esto ya seria un tema de transacciones distribuidas. Puedes provocar un error que revierta lo insertado ya en la parte final de tu proceso a menera de prueba.